# How to escape JSON string?

Tags: c#, json, escaping

Are there any classes/functions available to be used for easy JSON escaping? I'd rather not have to write my own.

Comment: JsonConvert.ToString() worked for me.

Comment: @MartinLottering Thank you!!! I have been looking for a way to get json to a formatted string. None of the answers below worked, but this did.

Answer (score 113):

I use [`System.Web.HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.javascriptstringencode(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string quoted = HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(input);
```

Comment: I used this to avoid the missing `System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode` in VS2015, but it needs the `(input, true)` parameter to include the actual quotes as well.

Comment: This was the missing link for me

Comment: I notice that this will encode single quotes ' as `\u0027`. However single quotes are valid in a JSON string.

Answer (score 80):

For those using the very popular Json.Net project from Newtonsoft the task is trivial:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

....
var s = JsonConvert.ToString(@"a\b");
Console.WriteLine(s);
....
```

This code prints:

"a\\b"

That is, the resulting string value contains the quotes as well as the escaped backslash.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this method for deserializing an encoded and escaped unc path.   My path `"WatchedPath": "\\\\myserver\\output"` becomes `"\"\\\\\\\\myserver\\\\output\""` which is pretty unacceptable.

Comment: The method above is not for deserializing - rater it is used when you want to create a JSON text manually and you have a C# string and need to gets its proper representation as a text.

Comment: @slestak, I think I am facing the same issue you were here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @GP24 IIRC, I did not.  Sorry I do not have any more info.

Comment: No problem, thanks for replying. I did this if it helps you: yourAnnoyingDoubleEncodedString.Replace("\\\\", "\\").Replace("\\\"", "\"");

Comment: This worked for me, but adding the outer quotes was a problem, since this is within code manually handling json-style text. I did this, then removed the outer quotes.

Answer (score 40):

Building on [the answer by Dejan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20935885/974531), what you can do is [import `System.Web.Helpers` .NET Framework assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14380681/974531), then use the following function:

```csharp
static string EscapeForJson(string s) {
  string quoted = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(s);
  return quoted.Substring(1, quoted.Length - 2);
}
```

The [`Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) call is required, since [`Encode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json.encode%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) automatically surrounds strings with double quotes.

Comment: Looks like System.Web.Helpers is not available before .Net 4.0

Comment: …and no more in Visual Studio 2015 too.

Comment: This is part of ASP.NET Web Pages 2.0. It can be added using NuGet. It is not part of the framework.

Answer (score 35):

Yep, just add the following function to your Utils class or something:

```
    public static string cleanForJSON(string s)
    {
        if (s == null || s.Length == 0) {
            return "";
        }

        char         c = '\0';
        int          i;
        int          len = s.Length;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len + 4);
        String       t;

        for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
            c = s[i];
            switch (c) {
                case '\\':
                case '"':
                    sb.Append('\\');
                    sb.Append(c);
                    break;
                case '/':
                    sb.Append('\\');
                    sb.Append(c);
                    break;
                case '\b':
                    sb.Append("\\b");
                    break;
                case '\t':
                    sb.Append("\\t");
                    break;
                case '\n':
                    sb.Append("\\n");
                    break;
                case '\f':
                    sb.Append("\\f");
                    break;
                case '\r':
                    sb.Append("\\r");
                    break;
                default:
                    if (c < ' ') {
                        t = "000" + String.Format("X", c);
                        sb.Append("\\u" + t.Substring(t.Length - 4));
                    } else {
                        sb.Append(c);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need to escape `/`?

Comment: I know this is an old answer and I'm happy to see this was given as I didn't want to rely on any external libraries, but I noticed that the default case for a control character will always return "\\u000X". I believe you need to cast the char first to an int. Consider replacing it with
`string t = "000" + ((int)c).ToString("X");`

Comment: The correct default case must be: `t = "000" + String.Format("{0:X}",(int) c);`

Comment: What we actually want is " `"\\u" + ((int)c).ToString("X4")`  (Although I think two Appends would be even better)

Answer (score 15):

I have used following code to escape the string value for json.
You need to add your '"' to the output of the following code:

```
public static string EscapeStringValue(string value)
{
    const char BACK_SLASH = '\\';
    const char SLASH = '/';
    const char DBL_QUOTE = '"';

    var output = new StringBuilder(value.Length);
    foreach (char c in value)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
            case SLASH:
                output.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", BACK_SLASH, SLASH);
                break;

            case BACK_SLASH:
                output.AppendFormat("{0}{0}", BACK_SLASH);
                break;

            case DBL_QUOTE:
                output.AppendFormat("{0}{1}",BACK_SLASH,DBL_QUOTE);
                break;

            default:
                output.Append(c);
                break;
        }
    }

    return output.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Do not use this code in production! This JSON escaping misses important special characters. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33799784

Comment: This code does not cover all the special cases. DO NOT use in production.

Comment: reinvent the wheel, and introduce some bug in special cases, is not a good answer

Answer (score 14):

In .Net Core 3+ and .Net 5+:

```
string escapedJsonString = JsonEncodedText.Encode(jsonString);
```

Comment: You need to mention that this does not do trivial escaping by default and the result might be much more escaped than you want. For example, quotes, triangle brackets and many letters will be converted to unicode characters and will only be usable if you unescape at the other end.

Answer (score 12):

The methods offered here are faulty. 
Why venture that far when you could just use System.Web.HttpUtility.JavaScriptEncode ?

If you're on a lower framework, you can just copy paste it from mono

Courtesy of the mono-project @
https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpUtility.cs

```
    public static string JavaScriptStringEncode(string value, bool addDoubleQuotes)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            return addDoubleQuotes ? "\"\"" : string.Empty;

        int len = value.Length;
        bool needEncode = false;
        char c;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            c = value[i];

            if (c >= 0 && c <= 31 || c == 34 || c == 39 || c == 60 || c == 62 || c == 92)
            {
                needEncode = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!needEncode)
            return addDoubleQuotes ? "\"" + value + "\"" : value;

        var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        if (addDoubleQuotes)
            sb.Append('"');

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            c = value[i];
            if (c >= 0 && c <= 7 || c == 11 || c >= 14 && c <= 31 || c == 39 || c == 60 || c == 62)
                sb.AppendFormat("\\u{0:x4}", (int)c);
            else switch ((int)c)
                {
                    case 8:
                        sb.Append("\\b");
                        break;

                    case 9:
                        sb.Append("\\t");
                        break;

                    case 10:
                        sb.Append("\\n");
                        break;

                    case 12:
                        sb.Append("\\f");
                        break;

                    case 13:
                        sb.Append("\\r");
                        break;

                    case 34:
                        sb.Append("\\\"");
                        break;

                    case 92:
                        sb.Append("\\\\");
                        break;

                    default:
                        sb.Append(c);
                        break;
                }
        }

        if (addDoubleQuotes)
            sb.Append('"');

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

This can be compacted into

```
// https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Json/System.Json/JsonValue.cs
public class SimpleJSON
{

    private static  bool NeedEscape(string src, int i)
    {
        char c = src[i];
        return c < 32 || c == '"' || c == '\\'
            // Broken lead surrogate
            || (c >= '\uD800' && c <= '\uDBFF' &&
                (i == src.Length - 1 || src[i + 1] < '\uDC00' || src[i + 1] > '\uDFFF'))
            // Broken tail surrogate
            || (c >= '\uDC00' && c <= '\uDFFF' &&
                (i == 0 || src[i - 1] < '\uD800' || src[i - 1] > '\uDBFF'))
            // To produce valid JavaScript
            || c == '\u2028' || c == '\u2029'
            // Escape "</" for <script> tags
            || (c == '/' && i > 0 && src[i - 1] == '<');
    }



    public static string EscapeString(string src)
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

        int start = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < src.Length; i++)
            if (NeedEscape(src, i))
            {
                sb.Append(src, start, i - start);
                switch (src[i])
                {
                    case '\b': sb.Append("\\b"); break;
                    case '\f': sb.Append("\\f"); break;
                    case '\n': sb.Append("\\n"); break;
                    case '\r': sb.Append("\\r"); break;
                    case '\t': sb.Append("\\t"); break;
                    case '\"': sb.Append("\\\""); break;
                    case '\\': sb.Append("\\\\"); break;
                    case '/': sb.Append("\\/"); break;
                    default:
                        sb.Append("\\u");
                        sb.Append(((int)src[i]).ToString("x04"));
                        break;
                }
                start = i + 1;
            }
        sb.Append(src, start, src.Length - start);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: This will also escape triangle brackets. Important for JS in HTML but not for JSON encoding per-se.

Answer (score 5):

I ran speed tests on some of these answers for a long string and a short string.  Clive Paterson's [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17691629/1418484) won by a good bit, presumably because the others are taking into account serialization options. Here are my results:

```
Apple Banana
System.Web.HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode: 140ms
System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode: 326ms
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.ToString: 230ms
Clive Paterson: 108ms

\\some\long\path\with\lots\of\things\to\escape\some\long\path\t\with\lots\of\n\things\to\escape\some\long\path\with\lots\of\"things\to\escape\some\long\path\with\lots"\of\things\to\escape
System.Web.HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode: 2849ms
System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode: 3300ms
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.ToString: 2827ms
Clive Paterson: 1173ms
```

And here is the test code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var testStr1 = "Apple Banana";
    var testStr2 = @"\\some\long\path\with\lots\of\things\to\escape\some\long\path\t\with\lots\of\n\things\to\escape\some\long\path\with\lots\of\""things\to\escape\some\long\path\with\lots""\of\things\to\escape";

    foreach (var testStr in new[] { testStr1, testStr2 })
    {
        var results = new Dictionary<string,List<long>>();

        for (var n = 0; n < 10; n++)
        {
            var count = 1000 * 1000;

            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                var s = System.Web.HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(testStr);
            }
            var t = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            results.GetOrCreate("System.Web.HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode").Add(t);

            sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                var s = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(testStr);
            }
            t = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            results.GetOrCreate("System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode").Add(t);

            sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                var s = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.ToString(testStr);
            }
            t = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            results.GetOrCreate("Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.ToString").Add(t);

            sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                var s = cleanForJSON(testStr);
            }
            t = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            results.GetOrCreate("Clive Paterson").Add(t);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(testStr);
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result.Key + ": " + Math.Round(result.Value.Skip(1).Average()) + "ms");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would also recommend using the [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) library mentioned, but if you have to escape unicode characters (e.g. \uXXXX format) in the resulting JSON string, you may have to do it yourself.  Take a look at [Converting Unicode strings to escaped ascii string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615559/converting-unicode-strings-to-escaped-ascii-string) for an example.

Answer (score 4):

I nice one-liner, used JsonConvert as others have but added substring to remove the added quotes and backslash.

```
 var escapedJsonString = JsonConvert.ToString(JsonString).Substring(1, JsonString.Length - 2);
```

Comment: I think you mean var escapedJsonString = JsonConvert.ToString(JsonString).Substring(1, JsonString.Length); - otherwise you chop 2 characters off the end of your string.  Remember, the \" are additional characters to the length of the original.

Answer (score 3):

What about System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(...) (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json.encode(v=vs.111).aspx)?

Answer (score 2):

```
String.Format("X", c);
```

That just outputs: X

Try this instead:

```
string t = ((int)c).ToString("X");

sb.Append("\\u" + t.PadLeft(4, '0'));
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a Json library at [Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/Json)

Answer (score 0):

I chose to use `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer`.

I have a small static helper class defined as follows:

```
internal static partial class Serialization
{
    static JavaScriptSerializer serializer;
    
    static Serialization()
    {
        serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
    }
    public static string ToJSON<T>(T obj)
    {
        return serializer.Serialize(obj);
    }
    public static T FromJSON<T>(string data)
    {
        if (Common.IsEmpty(data))
            return default(T);
        else
            return serializer.Deserialize<T>(data);
    }
}
```

To serialize anything I just call `Serialization.ToJSON(itemToSerialize)`

To deserialize I just call `Serialization.FromJSON<T>(jsonValueOfTypeT)`

Answer (score 0):

.NET 6 - System.Text.Json

var encodedText = JsonEncodedText.Encode(inputText);

Answer (score 0):

The C# method bellow is a more advanced optimization version using Span for small string inputs, to avoid heap allocation and StringBuilder for larger inputs to avoids excessive stack usage.

```
        public static string EscapeJsonText(string text) {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) return string.Empty;
        
        if (text.Length <= 256) {
            int count = 0;
            foreach (char c in text) {
                switch (c) {
                case '\\':
                case '\"':
                case '\b':
                case '\f':
                case '\n':
                case '\r':
                case '\t':
                    count += 2;
                    break;

                default:
                    count++;
                    break;
                }
            }

            Span<char> result = stackalloc char[count];
            count = 0;
            foreach (char c in text) {
                switch (c) {
                case '\\':
                case '\"':
                    result[count++] = '\\';
                    result[count++] = c;
                    break;

                case '\b':
                    result[count++] = '\\';
                    result[count++] = 'b';
                    break;

                case '\f':
                    result[count++] = '\\';
                    result[count++] = 'f';
                    break;

                case '\t':
                    result[count++] = '\\';
                    result[count++] = 't';
                    break;

                case '\n':
                    result[count++] = '\\';
                    result[count++] = 'n';
                    break;

                case '\r':
                    result[count++] = '\\';
                    result[count++] = 'r';
                    break;

                default:
                    result[count++] = c;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return result.ToString();
        }

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (char c in text) {
            switch (c) {
            case '\\': builder.Append("\\\\"); break;
            case '\"': builder.Append("\\\""); break;
            case '\b': builder.Append("\\b"); break;
            case '\f': builder.Append("\\f"); break;
            case '\n': builder.Append("\\n"); break;
            case '\r': builder.Append("\\r"); break;
            case '\t': builder.Append("\\t"); break;
            default: builder.Append(c); break;
            }
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }
```