# Best way to decode hex sequence of unicode characters to string

Tags: c#, unicode, decode

I'm working with C# .Net

I would like to know how to convert a Unicode form string like "\u1D0EC" 
(note that it's above "\uFFFF") to it's symbol... ""

Thanks For Advance!!!

Comment: Isn't unicode maximum value only FFFF? What's the meaning of unicode 1D0EC?

Comment: the closest solution that i've found was this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615559/converting-unicode-strings-to-escaped-ascii-string

but it worked only for below unicode "\uFFFF"

Comment: What do you mean to its symbol? During display time the symbol gets mapped to its visual representation. Do you want to convert to UTF8? to a particular encoding? Joel Spolsky has a good article on Unicode - it is confusing.

Comment: the meaning is:
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d0ec/index.htm

unicode can be above FFFF

Comment: i dont care not to see it in visual representation just need the string with the square in it.
in fileformat.com they have a "Browser Test Page" where you can see the matching square

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That Unicode codepoint is encoded in UTF32.  .NET and Windows encode Unicode in UTF16, you'll have to translate.  UTF16 uses "surrogate pairs" to handle codepoints above 0xffff, a similar kind of approach as UTF8.  The first code of the pair is 0xd800..dbff, the second code is 0xdc00..dfff.  Try this sample code to see that at work:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

class Program {
  static void Main(string[] args) {
    uint utf32 = uint.Parse("1D0EC", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    string s = Encoding.UTF32.GetString(BitConverter.GetBytes(utf32));
    foreach (char c in s.ToCharArray()) {
      Console.WriteLine("{0:X}", (uint)c);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert each sequence with [`int.Parse(String, NumberStyles)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c09yxbyt.aspx) and [`char.ConvertFromUtf32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.convertfromutf32.aspx):

```
string s = @"\U1D0EC";
string converted = char.ConvertFromUtf32(int.Parse(s.Substring(2), NumberStyles.HexNumber));
```

Answer (score 1):

I have recently push my FOSS Uncode Converter at Codeplex (http://unicode.codeplex.com)

you can convert whatever you want to Hex code and from Hex code to get the right character, also there is a full information character database.

I use this code

```
public static char ConvertHexToUnicode(string hexCode)
    {
        if (hexCode != string.Empty)
            return ((char)int.Parse(hexCode, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier));

        char empty = new char();
        return empty;
    }//end
```

you can see entire code on the http://unicode.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

It appears you just want this in your code... you can type it as a string literal using the escape code `\Uxxxxxxxx` (note that this is a *capital* U, and there *must* be 8 digits). For this example, it would be: `"\U0001D0EC"`.