# Silverlight to Javascript interop UTF encoding/decoding

Tags: javascript, silverlight, interop, binary, utf

How do I get both alerts, one invoked from silverlight and the other invoked from javascript, to show the same data in the same way.

eg. ���� != Ã½Ã¿Ã½Ã¿Ã½

System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Alert( data );

alert(parameters);

Silverlight3 code, sending data to javascript function:

```
         System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Alert( data );
         // data contains binary data read from files

         data = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));


        HtmlPage.Window.Eval("var data='"+data+"'makePOSTRequest('"+this.url+"',data);");
```

javascript function:

```
      function makePOSTRequest(url,parameters)
      {
      ...
        parameters = UTF8.encode(decode64(parameters));

        alert(parameters);
      ...
     }
```

javascript library:

```
    var UTF8 = {

        // public method for url encoding
        encode: function(string) {
            string = string.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");
            var utftext = "";

            for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {

                var c = string.charCodeAt(n);

                if (c < 128) {
                    utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
                }
                else if ((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
                    utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
                    utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
                }
                else {
                    utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
                    utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
                    utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
                }

            }

            return utftext;
        },

        // public method for url decoding
        decode: function(utftext) {
            var string = "";
            var i = 0;
            var c = c1 = c2 = 0;

            while (i < utftext.length) {

                c = utftext.charCodeAt(i);

                if (c < 128) {
                    string += String.fromCharCode(c);
                    i++;
                }
                else if ((c > 191) && (c < 224)) {
                    c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i + 1);
                    string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 31) << 6) | (c2 & 63));
                    i += 2;
                }
                else {
                    c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i + 1);
                    c3 = utftext.charCodeAt(i + 2);
                    string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 15) << 12) | ((c2 & 63) << 6) | (c3 & 63));
                    i += 3;
                }

            }

            return string;
        }

    }


    var keyStr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP" +
            "QRSTUVWXYZabcdef" +
            "ghijklmnopqrstuv" +
            "wxyz0123456789+/" +
            "=";

    function encode64(input) {
        var output = "";
        var chr1, chr2, chr3 = "";
        var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4 = "";
        var i = 0;

        do {
            chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
            chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
            chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);

            enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
            enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
            enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
            enc4 = chr3 & 63;

            if (isNaN(chr2)) {
                enc3 = enc4 = 64;
            } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
                enc4 = 64;
            }

            output = output +
        keyStr.charAt(enc1) +
        keyStr.charAt(enc2) +
        keyStr.charAt(enc3) +
        keyStr.charAt(enc4);
            chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "";
            enc1 = enc2 = enc3 = enc4 = "";
        } while (i < input.length);

        return output;
    }

    function decode64(input) {
        var output = "";
        var chr1, chr2, chr3 = "";
        var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4 = "";
        var i = 0;

        // remove all characters that are not A-Z, a-z, 0-9, +, /, or =
        var base64test = /[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g;
        if (base64test.exec(input)) {
            alert("There were invalid base64 characters in the input text.\n" +
           "Valid base64 characters are A-Z, a-z, 0-9, �+�, �/�, and �=�\n" +
           "Expect errors in decoding.");
        }
        input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");

        do {
            enc1 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc2 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc3 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc4 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));

            chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
            chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
            chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;

            output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);

            if (enc3 != 64) {
                output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
            }
            if (enc4 != 64) {
                output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
            }

            chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "";
            enc1 = enc2 = enc3 = enc4 = "";

        } while (i < input.length);

        return output;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to UTF-8 encode your characters, or do you just need a way to get these characters into the JavaScipt string?  I would recommend using unicode escape sequences (see [Unicode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Unicode) at at [Mozilla Developer Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en)).  For example, the copyright character is represented as "\u00A9".  The nice thing about unicode escape sequences is they can exist in a source file that is encoded using iso-8859-1, but still allow for any unicode character.

See [Converting Unicode strings to escaped ascii string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615559/converting-unicode-strings-to-escaped-ascii-string) for an example of how to do generate these escape sequences in C#.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be encoding the data as UTF-8 twice,  you do it in silverlight:-

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data)
```

and you do it again in Javascript

```
parameters = UTF8.encode(decode64(parameters));
```

are you sure this line shouldn't be:-

```
parameters = UTF8.decode(decode64(parameters));
```

?

Is there a reason you're not using `WebClient` or `WebRequest` inside Silverlight to do this posting?