# javascript unterminated string constant

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have the following function which I pass in a value, but this value is coming from the database. However I get the following javascript when doing the following:

```
showrootcausedetails('showrootcause',true,'<%# eval("Root Cause Analysis").ToString() %>')
```

I know I have to escape the characters, but How can I do that without knowing what is in the actual string?

Thanks,

Jacob

Answer (score 7):

Call [`Server.JavaScriptStringEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.javascriptstringencode.aspx).

Comment: +1 - OP might be on less than .NET 4.0 though. There's some solutions to that here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920752/is-there-a-standard-way-to-encode-a-net-string-into-javascript-string-for-use-in

Comment: Do I need to reference something before using that function ?

Comment: I am getting the the same error text for this: `var setScript = "<script></script>";`