# Javascript function not getting called when ' (single quote)is present

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net

I am calling javascript function through:

```
    <a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='javascript:onEditRevPrepare("<%# 
Convert.ToString(Eval("ReviewTitle")))%>")'>
```

When single quot (') is present in  `Eval("ReviewTitle")` its not calling the function.

I tried with:

```
Convert.ToString(Eval("ReviewTitle"))).Replace("'","\")
```

But this does not worked.

Also tried with:

```
 <a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='javascript:onEditRevPrepare("&quot;<%# 
    Convert.ToString(Eval("ReviewTitle")))%>&quot;")'>
```

But this also not worked.

**EDIT**

As and when i add ' or / in replace i stops getting line of javascript , which indicates function calling is not correct:

[image]

Please look at the broken line after replace

Answer (score 1):

At it's simplest, you could

```
//Convert.ToString(Eval("ReviewTitle"))).Replace("'","\") //broken
  Convert.ToString(Eval("ReviewTitle"))).Replace("'","\\'").Replace("\"","\\\"")
```

However, you really should look at [javascript encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920752/is-there-a-standard-way-to-encode-a-net-string-into-javascript-string-for-use-i) for a more robust solution.

Comment: @SagarS.Dhanorkar I don't see it mentioned. Take a closer look to spot the difference.

Comment: @SagarS.Dhanorkar : I made a mistake. Try again with the changes above.