# filter bad/special characters in c#

Tags: c#

I have a c# program which is injecting strings into some javascript, the problem is that in those string there are special characters which are breaking the js and end into "illegal token".

I can't identify what special character is use. Is there a way to filter everything ?

I've tried things like that without success:

```
  retval = new string(input.Where(c => !char.IsControl(c)).ToArray());
  retval = retval.Replace("\u200B", "");
```

Any idea or hint is very welcomed

Comment: May be you should do the *reversed* thing: leave *right* characters, say `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9` and remove all the other characters?

Comment: and also leave punctuation, I'm a total newbie to c# if you could provide a piece of code it would be very nice of you

Comment: What are "bad" characters at all? You can always store a positive list, for example in a `HashSet<char>` and use `input.Where(positiveChars.Contains)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3528628/3928617

Comment: I think philippe is right, thank you very much