# Invalid Character using json

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, json.net

I read a record from my sql server database into a datatable.  From there I use newtonsoft's JSON for .NET and run it through

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DataTable)
```

I get the following json string output:

```
[{"Type":"Support-D325","condition":"#2 support beam 1/2\" crack","Length":245.0,"Date_Found":"2018-08-09T08:01:51"}]
```

and store it in a session variable.  Later, client-side I use

```
data = $.parseJSON('<%= Session("JSONDataTable") %>');
```

but get the INVALID CHARACTER error.  Now I'm guessing its the **#2 support beam 1/2\" crack** that's doing causing the problem. Is there some JSON command that can fix this so I don't throw the error?

Thank you

Comment: The json string looks properly formatted.  The first question I have is what does `'<%= Session("JSONDataTable") %>'` generate to in the actual script?

Comment: See [Is there a standard way to encode a .NET string into JavaScript string for use in MS Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2920752); namely, use  [`HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.javascriptstringencode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_HttpUtility_JavaScriptStringEncode_System_String_)

Comment: Also, if `Session("JSONDataTable")` is the json string you pasted before, you should be able to do something as simple as `data = <%= Session("JSONDataTable") %>` without having to try to force it to be a string to be parsed.

Comment: Please post the exact error you are receiving; it should tell you what the invalid character is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need JSON.parse I believe. Just do it like this:

```
data = <%= Session("JSONDataTable") %>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the "\" character, I recommend that you do the transform to string and replace it, then show it again:

```
data = $.parseJSON('<%= Session("JSONDataTable") %>');
```

Comment: i figured it was the escape character, but transform it to what?

Comment: convert it to string and apply replace