# How to convert verbatim string to regular unicode

Tags: c#, encoding, exchange-server, plaintext

I'm pro-grammatically reading emails from Exchange 2010 that have been sent in plain text. In my parsing tests to ensure the email is valid I do a series of validations, one being checking the beginning text (`StartsWith` precisely). When I manually copy and paste the email from Exchange into Visual Studio 2008 the start of the email looks like `\r\n \x0002\r\n`. I believe `\x0002` is a smiley face (STX) judging from my research. However, programatically retrieving the email from Exchange as well as viewing it in Outlook the `\x0002` character displays as a `ㅁ`. Ideally, I would like to parse what's retrieved from Exchange (`\r\n ㅁ\r\n`) and convert it to `\r\n \x0002\r\n`.

For what it's worth, ReSharper is the one who converted the original string to include `\x0002`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want one of the following:

```
Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(myString);
Encoding.Unicode.GetChars(myString);
```

To format a `char` or a `byte` as a unicode character (e.g. "\uFF66" or "\x0002") see the following question:

[Converting Unicode strings to escaped ascii string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615559/converting-unicode-strings-to-escaped-ascii-string)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was *almost* at that point of my attempts. How do you get it to return `\x0002` as opposed to the smiley face?

Comment: @gcso That was actually trickier than I though it would be - I've updated my answer.  For your purposes I think you are better comparing against a character, rather than converting a character to its escaped string representation.