# FTP special character in password?

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, ftpwebresponse

I am trying to login to a ftp server. Using the following code in C#.

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp-server");

request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
// This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
//request.AuthenticationLevel = System.Net.Security.AuthenticationLevel.MutualAuthRequired;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("userName", "password!#£");
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

However the login fails when the password contains some special charaters. e.g ('!' or '£')? I get the following exception.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (530) Not logged in.
  at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.SyncRequestCallback(Object obj)
  at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.RequestCallback(Object obj)
  at System.Net.CommandStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
  at System.IO.Stream.Close()
  at System.IO.Stream.Dispose()
  at System.Net.ConnectionPool.Destroy(PooledStream pooledStream)
  at System.Net.ConnectionPool.PutConnection(PooledStream pooledStream, Object owningObject, Int32 creationTimeout, Bo
ean canReuse)
  at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.FinishRequestStage(RequestStage stage)
  at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetResponse()
  at FtpClientTest.Program.FtpWebRequest()
```

I don't get any exception when the password does not contain any special characters.

Comment: Why are you UTF-8 encoding the password?  What happens if you just pass it as an native string?

Comment: does `doesEncodeUTF8("xxxxxxx")` retrun escaped ascii string?? try this may it will solve the problem.. [Converting Unicode strings to escaped ascii string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615559/converting-unicode-strings-to-escaped-ascii-string)  
I have explored all classes of `NetworkCredential Class` but all uses string type password, event `secureString` also have same char/string type values..   i am agree with @Joe that you should native string type secure password..

Comment: @Joe: I tried first the native string and it did not work. Then I tried using UTF8 encoding which also dis not work.

Comment: @Niranjan: I tried the to EncodeNonAsciChars and that also did not work.

Comment: Trace Ftp Log to check whether this problem regarding server or some other. check this link [How to troubleshoot your System.Net code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ncl/archive/2008/07/25/how-to-troubleshoot-your-system-net-code.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

what ftp server is it? can you login using other programs? if yes, use [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to compare what goes over the wire.

So it is probably just ANSI encoding, so try

```
var secureString = new SecureString();
foreach (var b in Encoding.Default.GetBytes("password!#£"))
    secureString.AppendChar((char)b);

request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("userName", secureString);
```

Comment: I can login using ftp command from my Windows 7 Command prompt

Comment: @Amitabh updated my post, no promise, but worth a try i guess!