# how do I convert unicode characters to backslashed values - to solve json_encode issue

Tags: php, json, unicode

I'm trying to pull sport players from my database that are already stored as unicode values. when calling json_encode it gives up when it hits unicode characters in the format i've got:

```
$values = array('a'=>'BERDYCH, Tomáš','b'=>'FEDERER, Roger');
echo json_encode($values);
```

the result is

{"a":"BERDYCH, Tom","b":"FEDERER, Roger"}

You can see 'Tom' was cut-off because it reached the unicode characters.

I understand json_encode only handles \uxxxx style characters but the problem is my database of thousands of sporting competitors already contains unicode stored values, so somehow I need to convert á type characters into \uxxxx without doing updates to my data source.

Any ideas?

Comment: `json_encode` handles Unicode just fine, at least it's supposed to. Are you sure your text is UTF-8 encoded? Show us a `bin2hex` of the text.

Comment: echo bin2hex('BERDYCH, Tomáš');
gives me
424552445943482c20546f6de19a

Comment: maybe i've got to set an environment variable or something? does the above code work for you and give you back a json encoded version of Tomas Berdych's full name?

Answer (score 1):

`json_encode()` does this when it gets characters that are not valid UTF-8 characters.

If you are fetching data from the database, the most likely reason is that your connection is not UTF-8 encoded, and you are getting ISO-8859-1 data from your queries.

Show your database code for a suggestion how to change this.

> I understand json_encode only handles \uxxxx style characters

This is not true. `json_encode()` *outputs* Unicode characters encoded this way, but it doesn't *expect* them in the incoming data.

Comment: thanks Pekka but the two lines of code above causes the same issue, even without using a database?

Comment: @Luc is your source file UTF-8 encoded? (Usually in the "Save As" dialog of your IDE)

Comment: Ahh, i see Pekka - thanks for that!
1) i've saved my PHP as UFT-8 encoded
2) i'm investing changing my columns, database tables and sql default settings to encode default values as utf-8

Answer (score 1):

Your source code and/or the data coming from the database is not encoded in UTF-8. I'd guess it's one of the specialized ISO-8859 encodings, but I'm not sure. When saving your source code, make sure it's saved in UTF-8. When getting data from the database, make sure you're setting the connection to utf8.

See [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) and [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/).

Comment: Thanks deceze, some very helpful links there. Any new projects from now on the first thing i'll be doing is setting up utf-8 from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure they are UTF8, encode all values in your array

```
$values = array_map('utf8_encode', $values);
```

If that doesn't help use mb_detect_encoding() and mb_convert_encoding() to change language specific encoding to UTF8.

Comment: Please do not suggest `utf8_encode` without clarifying that the source needs to be in Latin1. Otherwise `utf8_encode` is useless! And "trying" or "guessing" is not the solution when it comes to encodings. *Know* what encoding you're dealing with!

Comment: There's more likely a better solution: Fixing the problem at its root. (Edit: deceze beat me to the punch!)

Answer (score 0):

It's a c# question, but take a look at [Converting Unicode strings to escaped ascii string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615559/converting-unicode-strings-to-escaped-ascii-string) for an implementation that does this.