# Converting Unicode to a string

Tags: java, string, unicode

Consider the following Java code:

```
String str = "\u8ba9\u4ed6\u51fa\u6d77\u4e86";
// ...
System.out.print(str);
```

I want to get the characters from `str`.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: What language is that in? Please put it in the tags.

Comment: Here is a .Net example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615559/converting-unicode-strings-to-escaped-ascii-string   Not your language, but it should be trivial to translate.

Comment: Is there a Class in JDK and it has a method to complete this?

Comment: You don't need to doing any task, all `String` in java are `Unicode` so your `str` variable is unicode and when output it  at console you will see characters correctly.(I guess your characters are Chines language)

Comment: Yes,they are Chinese language.But the output is still the unicode,like "\u8ba9\u4ed6\u51fa\u6d77\u4e86".

Comment: When I run your code I get 5 questionmarks because I don't have the correct character set installed I guess. "\u8ba9" is Java notation for a unicode character, and quite different from "\\u8ba9" which is Java notation for a backslash followed by "u8ba9".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look in this issue in [Commons-IO JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IO-309). Hopefully the class `UnicodeUnescapeReader` will be integrated in `commons-io` in the future. Nevertheless you can integrate it in your codebase and easily use it:

```
String str = "\u8ba9\u4ed6\u51fa\u6d77\u4e86";
StringReader sr = new StringReader(str);
UnicodeUnescapeReader uur = new UnicodeUnescapeReader(sr);

StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(); 
for(int c = uur.read(); c != -1; c = uur.read())
{ 
  buf.append((char)c); 
} 
System.out.println(buf.toString());
```

This outputs is this: `让他出海了`

Alternative with commons-io:

```
StringReader sr = new StringReader(str);
UnicodeUnescapeReader uur = new UnicodeUnescapeReader(sr);
System.out.println(IOUtils.toString(uur));
```

Comment: I got it,the InputStream make my 'str' like "\\u8ba9\\u4ed6\\u51fa\\u6d77\\u4e86".tank you everyone.

Comment: @user1349121 You may mark this as the accepted answer to indicate for others to not to investigate this issue anymore.

Comment: `UnicodeUnescapeReader` doest not exist in the `commons-io`, [janino](https://janino-compiler.github.io/janino/) contains it.

Answer (score 1):

You can get in java

```
char c = "\uFFFF".toCharArray()[0];
System.out.println(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

more easy way

```java
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-text -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
    <version>1.9</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(str);
```