# Implementing Google transliterate API using REST and C#, facing unicode and parsing issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, rest, unicode

I have been trying to use Google Transliterate API using the RESTful approach as its easy to do so through server side language (C# here).

So, I came across this URL format: http://www.google.com/transliterate/indic?tlqt=1&langpair=en|hi&text=bharat%2Cindia&tl_app=3 which returns the JSON in the format:

```
[
{
"ew" : "bharat",
"hws" : [
"भारत","भरत","भरात","भारात","बहरत",
]
},
{
"ew" : "india",
"hws" : [
"इंडिया","इन्डिया","इण्डिया","ईन्डिया","इनडिया",
]
},
]
```

I tried `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse` to get the JSON but it returned values in Unicode on the web browser, such as:

```
[ { "ew" : "bharat", "hws" : [ "\u092D\u093E\u0930\u0924","\u092D\u0930\u0924","\u092D\u0930\u093E\u0924","\u092D\u093E\u0930\u093E\u0924","\u092C\u0939\u0930\u0924", ] }, { "ew" : "india", "hws" : [ "\u0907\u0902\u0921\u093F\u092F\u093E","\u0907\u0928\u094D\u0921\u093F\u092F\u093E","\u0907\u0923\u094D\u0921\u093F\u092F\u093E","\u0908\u0928\u094D\u0921\u093F\u092F\u093E","\u0907\u0928\u0921\u093F\u092F\u093E", ] }, ]
```

So, I applied this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615559/converting-unicode-strings-to-escaped-ascii-string) and passed the JSON **string** via it, and it returned:

```
[ { "ew" : "bharat", "hws" : [ "भारत","भरत","भरात","भारात","बहरत", ] }, { "ew" : "india", "hws" : [ "इंडिया","इन्डिया","इण्डिया","ईन्डिया","इनडिया", ] }, ]
```

**FIRST QUESTION**: Am I doing it right so far? Because in the browser it DOES NOT show the last `" ] "`, however `" ] "` exists in the HTML source (not sure why that happened). Also, when I try to parse it, using (I might be wrong using this technique):

```
var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var dict = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(the_JSON_string);
```

Its giving me error saying:

```
Invalid array passed in, extra trailing ','.
```

**SECOND QUESTION**: If I am doing right so far, can I get some help *parsing the Hindi words*? What approach should I take using preferably `System.Web.Script.Serialization;`. Eventually I want to grab the Hindi text for further processing.

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) to parse json strings. Below code(with your sample string) works and you don't need to do anything to unescape those characters. Json parsers will handle it for you.

```
string json = @"[ { ""ew"" : ""bharat"", ""hws"" : [ ""\u092D\u093E\u0930\u0924"",""\u092D\u0930\u0924"",""\u092D\u0930\u093E\u0924"",""\u092D\u093E\u0930\u093E\u0924"",""\u092C\u0939\u0930\u0924"", ] }, { ""ew"" : ""india"", ""hws"" : [ ""\u0907\u0902\u0921\u093F\u092F\u093E"",""\u0907\u0928\u094D\u0921\u093F\u092F\u093E"",""\u0907\u0923\u094D\u0921\u093F\u092F\u093E"",""\u0908\u0928\u094D\u0921\u093F\u092F\u093E"",""\u0907\u0928\u0921\u093F\u092F\u093E"", ] }, ]";

dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
MessageBox.Show(obj[0].hws[0].ToString());
```

Comment: thanks a lot. It totally works. Is there a way I can get to know the size of obj ? obj.Length does not work. Because the number of parameters could be many, so I might want to loop through the same. Thanks.

Comment: @DevDreamer You can write `var length = obj.Count;` or `foreach (var item in obj)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(item.hws[0].ToString());
            }`

Comment: can you please help me with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095188/parsing-the-json-with-multilingual-text-using-system-web-script-serialization-or Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can remove last comma like a below way

```
  the_JSON_string =  the_JSON_string.Remove(the_JSON_string.LastIndexOf(','));
```