# Parsing the JSON with multilingual text using System.Web.Script.Serialization or System.Web.* library

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, rest

I had [asked this question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862004/implementing-google-transliterate-api-using-rest-and-c-facing-unicode-and-pars). The solution using Newtonsoft worked great until I deployed the website on web hosting server, where its [giving me nightmares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091141/missing-a-using-directive-or-an-assembly-reference-issue-after-deploying-an-asp/12091763#comment16159030_12091763). Therefore, I am planning to use some `System.Web` libraries so that I don't have to deal with *.dlls and such and I can easily deploy my website.

Can someone help me [parse the same json output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862004/implementing-google-transliterate-api-using-rest-and-c-facing-unicode-and-pars) using `System.Web.Script.Serialization` or any `System library`? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope your real json string is valid since the one you posted is corrupted but Json.Net tolerates it.

The only trick is deserializing to this funny type `List<Dictionary<string,object>>`

Here is an example with corrected json(removed trailing `,`s)

```
string json = @"[ { ""ew"" : ""bharat"", ""hws"" : [ ""\u092D\u093E\u0930\u0924"",""\u092D\u0930\u0924"",""\u092D\u0930\u093E\u0924"",""\u092D\u093E\u0930\u093E\u0924"",""\u092C\u0939\u0930\u0924"" ] }, { ""ew"" : ""india"", ""hws"" : [ ""\u0907\u0902\u0921\u093F\u092F\u093E"",""\u0907\u0928\u094D\u0921\u093F\u092F\u093E"",""\u0907\u0923\u094D\u0921\u093F\u092F\u093E"",""\u0908\u0928\u094D\u0921\u093F\u092F\u093E"",""\u0907\u0928\u0921\u093F\u092F\u093E"" ] } ]";
var list = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Dictionary<string,object>>>(json);

foreach (var dict in list)
{
    var ew  = (string)dict["ew"];
    var firstValOfHws = ((ArrayList)dict["hws"])[0];
}
```

**--EDIT--**

OK, This should work

```
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Result>));
var result = (List<Result>)serializer.ReadObject(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)));

public class Result
{
    public string ew;
    public List<string> hws;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. However, unfortunately, the json is corrupted ( http://www.google.com/transliterate/indic?tlqt=1&langpair=en%7Chi&text=india%2Cbharat&tl_app=3 ). Any hack around it?