# Using Google Transliterate [NOT TRANSLATE] API in Android

Tags: transliteration, liquidcore

The project that I'm working on mandates (by law) the name of the business to be displayed to the users in the regional language.

The best option that I could find was Google Transliterate. I'm aware Google Transliterate API has been officially deprecated as of May 26, 2011 but is still available to be used - which solves by need.

So my question is - How can I use Transliterate API without the need to open a web browser? When a user keys in a Edit Text say for e.g. "Baskin Robbins" I would like to get it transliterated behind the scene. I'm on minSdk 10.

Any pointers to working samples would be very much appreciated. Is LiquidCore as possibility? https://github.com/LiquidPlayer/LiquidCore . Any known implementation of Liquidcore & Transliterate? Please advise.

Comment: www.google.com/transliterate/indic?tlqt=1&langpair=en|ta&text=baskin%20robbins

Answer (score 0):

www.google.com/transliterate/indic?tlqt=1&langpair=en|ta&text=baskin%20robbins

Also see here

[Implementing Google transliterate API using REST and C#, facing unicode and parsing issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862004/implementing-google-transliterate-api-using-rest-and-c-facing-unicode-and-pars?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)