# How to get roman hindi from google translate api?

Tags: google-translate, google-translation-api

While using google translate api for english to hindi translation, we are trying to fetch translated roman hindi for an english search query, searching for suitable method.

Comment: Do you mean "transliterated"?

Comment: Yes, transliteration. For eg: "shoes" when translated in hindi gives "जूते", but we need "joote"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49828389/using-google-transliterate-not-translate-api-in-android ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the transliteration from English `en` to Hindi `hi`, which means that the result will the translated text with only Latin characters, is not supported. As per the comments, from English `shoes` the expected output would be `joote`. However, the output is `जूते`.

There is an already open Feature request within [Google's Issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker), [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/189744674), addressing the Transliteration for the Cloud Translation API. Thus, you can click on the **+1** button and leave a comment so the Googlers know this issue is also relevant to you. Lastly, I should point out that this platform is used to track bugs and feature requests made by the costumers.