# How to convert these string to normal string?

Tags: c#, string, unicode, converters

I have these strings:

```
\x22vi\x26#7879;t\\u003Cb\\u003E nam\\u003C\\/b\\u003E\x22
\x22vi\x26#7879;t\\u003Cb\\u003E nam net\\u003C\\/b\\u003E\x22
\x22vi\x26#7879;t\\u003Cb\\u003E b\x26#7843;n \x26#273;\x26#7891;\\u003C\\/b\\u003E\x22
\x22vi\x26#7879;t\\u003Cb\\u003E ti\x26#7871;n\\u003C\\/b\\u003E\x22
```

I get it from google autocompleter with keyword is [việt](https://www.google.com.vn/s?hl=vi&gs_nf=1&tok=47VI6ikAHWQeEbETu4Z-1w&cp=4&gs_id=12&xhr=t&q=vi%E1%BB%87t&pf=p&safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=be3c25b6da637b79&biw=1366&bih=362&tch=1&ech=8&psi=ojJEULrqIcqJrAeA4YCIDQ.1346646665105.1). How to convert it to normal string by C#?, like this:

```
việt nam
việt nam net
việt nam bản đồ
việt tiến
```

***Note: that strings can have unicode character.*** Thank for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting Unicode strings to escaped ascii string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615559/converting-unicode-strings-to-escaped-ascii-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

read this

[Convert a Unicode string to an escaped ASCII string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615559/converting-unicode-strings-to-escaped-ascii-string)

http://konfabulator.wikia.com/wiki/Convert_HTML_entities