# Convert string to unicode representation

Tags: c#, .net, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting Unicode strings to escaped ascii string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615559/converting-unicode-strings-to-escaped-ascii-string)

How can I convert `ä...` into something like  `\u0131...` ?

is there any Function for doing this ?

p.s :

beside this way :  [ sorry @Kendall Frey :-)]

```
char a = 'ä';
string escape = "\\u" + ((int)a).ToString("X").PadLeft(4, '0');
```

Comment: @JonSkeet isn't there any READY function ?

Comment: It's *ready* for you to cut and paste...

Comment: also `string.isNullOrEmpty` code can be cut and paste , my question is regarding a ready one like `string.isNullOrEmpty`

Comment: @RoyiNamir There is. I wrote it for you.

Comment: Your answer is "no". There is no built-in function for this. You'll have to use @KendallFrey's solution.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here's a function to convert a char to an escape sequence:

```
string GetEscapeSequence(char c)
{
    return "\\u" + ((int)c).ToString("X4");
}
```

It isn't gonna get much better than a one-liner.

And no, there's no built-in function as far as I know.

Comment: I suspect there's a way of getting the left-padding correct in the format string instead of calling PadLeft though...

Comment: @JonSkeet -- I believe just changing to `ToString("X4")` and dropping the `PadLeft` will do the trick.

Comment: Fine. But I thought of it first :P

Comment: @KendallFrey: Yes, definitely :)

Comment: @JonB What do you mean? Check the time I edited.

Comment: Mostly for fun: `var s = "ä";   s = new string(s.SelectMany(c => (int)c > 127 ? ("\\u" + ((int)c).ToString("X4")).ToArray() : new char[] { c }).ToArray());`

Comment: And it should be possible to use `var allEscapes = string.Concat("example".Select(GetEscapeSequence));` to create escape sequences for all code units in the string `"example"`.

Comment: 2019 edition: `string EscapeSequence(char c) => $@"\u{(int)c:X4}";`

Answer (score 9):

There is no built-in function AFAIK. Here is one pretty silly solution that works. But Kendall Frey provided much better variant.

```
string GetUnicodeString(string s)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (char c in s)
    {
        sb.Append("\\u");
        sb.Append(String.Format("{0:x4}", (int)c));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```