# Replace special character with unicode character in a string c#

Tags: c#, string

Beginning in c#, haven't seen a duplicate. What I want to do is:

this string: `İntersport`
transform to this string: `\u0130ntersport`

I found a way to convert everything in unicode but not to convert only the special character.

thanks in advance for your help

edit:

I have tried your solution:

```
 string source = matchedWebIDDest.name;
 string parsedNameUnicode = string.Concat(source.Select(c => c < 32 || c > 255 ? "\\u" + ((int)c).ToString("x4") : c.ToString()));
```

But I get : "System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[Syst‌​em.Char,System.Strin‌​g]"

Comment: You could iterate over each char and use the solution provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291339/convert-string-to-unicode-representation to convert the character and then build a new string.

Comment: I saw this but it would convert all my character .. and not only those I need to convert

Comment: I've copied+pasted your code, changed `matchedWebIDDest.name` to `"İntersport"`, added `Console.Write(parsedNameUnicode);` and I've seen  `\u0130ntersport` outcome

Comment: this is weird it's working with you no Linq solution, I'm wondering why ... Thanks a lot for your help and patience

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "special character." İ is a letter in at least one language's alphabet. Letters of an alphabet are not normally termed "special."  What is the larger purpose in changing the representation of the text in a string (to a format that can be stored in a C# source file that doesn't use the default encoding of UTF-8)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try using *Linq*:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  string source = "İntersport";

  // you may want to change 255 into 127 if you want standard ASCII table
  string target = string.Concat(source
    .Select(c => c < 32 || c > 255  
       ? "\\u" + ((int)c).ToString("x4") // special symbol: command one or above Ascii 
       : c.ToString()));                 // within ascii table [32..255]

  // \u0130ntersport
  Console.Write(target);
```

**Edit:** No *Linq* solution:

```
  string source = "İntersport";

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  foreach (char c in source) 
    if (c < 32 || c > 255)
      sb.Append("\\u" + ((int)c).ToString("x4"));
    else
      sb.Append(c);

  string target = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: string doesn't have the Select method in my c# version ... how should I handle this ?

Comment: @François Richard: `string` itself doesn't have `Select`, but Linq provides an *extension method* `Select` for `IEnumerable<T>` (`string` is `IEnumerable<char>`). Please, be sure that you put `using System.Linq;` within other `using`s

Comment: @François Richard: if you *don't want* using *Linq* you can build the `target` string with a help of `StringBuilder`, see my edit.

Comment: ok I see. But now it returns "System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Char,System.String]"

Comment: target become the string above =/ what did i do wrong ?

Comment: @François Richard: it seems that you've omited `string.Concat(...)`