# Replacing unicode characters in string in C#

Tags: c#, string, unicode, utf-8

I have string for example:

```
string str = "ĄĆŹ - ćwrą";
```

How can i replace ĄĆŹ - ćą with they shortcuts?
Result for that example string should be:

```
str = "\u0104\u0106\u0179 \u2013 \u0107wr\u0105"
```

Is there any fast replacement method? I dont want to use .Replace for each character...

Comment: Replace does strings..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting Unicode strings to escaped ascii string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615559/converting-unicode-strings-to-escaped-ascii-string)

Comment: Thanks, i also just found it. Problem solved. @Sayse i don't want to use .Replace hundreds of times

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Converting to a JSON string like that is more cumbersome than it should be, mainly because you need to work with Unicode code points which in practice means calling `char.ConvertToUtf32`. In order to do that, you need to somehow handle surrogate pairs; `System.Globalization.StringInfo` can help with that.

Here's a function that uses these building blocks to perform the conversion:

```
string str = "ĄĆŹ - ćwrą";

public string ToJsonString(string s)
{
    var enumerator = StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(s);
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        var unicodeChar = enumerator.GetTextElement();
        var codePoint = char.ConvertToUtf32(unicodeChar, 0);
        if (codePoint < 0x80) {
            sb.Append(unicodeChar);
        }
        else if (codePoint < 0xffff) {
            sb.Append("\\u").Append(codePoint.ToString("x4"));
        }
        else {
            sb.Append("\\u").Append((codePoint & 0xffff).ToString("x4"));
            sb.Append("\\u").Append(((codePoint >> 16) & 0xffff).ToString("x4"));
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```