# How to send an email with its text/html encoded in UTF-8 using SendGrid for C#?

Tags: c#, email, smtp, sendgrid

I'm trying to send emails that contains special characters like á, é, ó, í, ú, etc. My code looks like this:

```
try
{
   Mail message = Mail.GetInstance();
   foreach (Users u in users)
   {
       message.AddBcc(u.Email);
   }
   message.From = new MailAddress(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudConfigurationManager
       .GetSetting("emailFrom"), Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudConfigurationManager
       .GetSetting("emailFromName"));
   message.Subject = Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudConfigurationManager
       .GetSetting("emailSubject");

   message.Html = "<meta charset=\"UTF-8\"/>" + 
       Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("emailText1") + 
       " " + address+ ".<br/>" + 
       Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("emailText2");

   var transport = SMTP.GetInstance(new NetworkCredential(
       Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("emailLogin"), 
       Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("emailPass")));
   transport.Deliver(message);
   isEmailSent = true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message + " \n " + ex.InnerException + " \n " + ex.StackTrace);
    isEmailSent = false;
}
```

I tried to specify the charset in the Html I'm sending but it doesn't work, instead of sending this `San Jerónimo Amanal`, this is what is being sent `San JerÃ³nimo Amanal`.

How can I send it in the correct encoding? Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I tried this two approches:

```
   message.Html = "<meta charset=\"UTF-8\"/>" + 
       Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("emailText1") + 
       " " + address+ ".<br/>" + 
       Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("emailText2");
```

And this:

```
   message.Html = Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting
       ("emailText1") + " " + address+ ".<br/>" + 
       Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("emailText2");
```

But the email is still being sent with the wrong encoding.

**EDIT 2**

I tried the answer on this question [Converting Unicode strings to escaped ascii string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615559/converting-unicode-strings-to-escaped-ascii-string), more especifically, I tried the method `EncodeNonAsciiCharacters` but I got this in the email `San Jer\u00c3\u00b3nimo Amanal`. Did I take the wrong approach in this one?

Comment: I think the problem is that although you may have stored your data in UTF8, reading it into a .NET string will cause it to be converted back to double-byte.  If you omit the meta charset tag, does it look right?

Comment: It still sends the message without the proper encoding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it took some time, but at least I found a way to send the email without the special characters, I had to [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_normalization#Normal_forms) the string I got with *Normalization Form Compatibility Decomposition*, which is done through the String class' [Normalize method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebza6ck1.aspx) like this:

```
string normalizedString = InString.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKD);
```

With this, quoting from wikipedia:

> *characters are decomposed by compatibility, and multiple combining
> characters are arranged in a specific order.*

Meaning if there's also a character whose compability is represented by two characters, then it will be replace by said characters. With characters like é, it will be replaced by e.