# how to decode string contain \uXXXX in c# properly?

Tags: c#, utf-8

I have a program in C# that reads java properties file and get the string content of the file. and the java properties file contain a string which look like this

DICOM_Nodes=W\u0119z\u0142y DICOM

but when StreamReader reads this line,

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file,Encoding.UTF8);
```

it return the line in the same way (with the \u0119 instead of 'ę')

but if i do

```
string value = "W\u0119z\u0142y DICOM";
```

then c# understands it perfectly

**sample output:**

from StreamReader: W\u0119z\u0142y DICOM

from value: Węzły DICOM

anyone know how to conver the string from StreamReader to a readable form?

Comment: Why you don't store `ę` in file instead `\u0119`?

Comment: This code has a helper method called `DecodeEncodedNonAsciiCharacters` that appears to do what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1615860/231316

Comment: The `\uxxxx` part of the string is parsed by the compiler.  You don't have the compiler around anymore to read that file.  Buy yourself a copy of the New York Times Sunday Edition and whack that Java programmer over the head with it.  If that doesn't produce a response then use this answer:

Comment: Hamlet: i got the file from Translator, there are thousands of those.


Chris: Thanks that's what i need!