# how to convert UniCode codes from HTML to normal string c#

Tags: c#, unicode

I have to convert unicode strings to normal strings.

for an example, convert this: "\u05e0\u05d9\u05e8\u05d5\u05d5" to: "נירוו" (hebrew letters).

that's what i already tried:

```
        private string Convert(string S)
    {
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes(S));
    }
```

it returns wierd characters. for example: �����

How can i do it in c# ?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the original encoding?  There are UTF8?  UTF16?  UTF32?

Comment: It's UniCode, and i want to convert it to normal characters. (hebrew letters)

Comment: There is more than one "UniCode" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Mapping_and_encodings

Comment: What does “from HTML” mean in the question title? I don’t see anything HTML-related in the question.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela i mean i'm trying to convert text from HTML document.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting Unicode strings to escaped ascii string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615559/converting-unicode-strings-to-escaped-ascii-string)

Comment: I don't see any HTML anywhere. `"\u05e0\u05d9\u05e8\u05d5\u05d5"` and `"נירוו"` are the exact same string, stop doing anything to them. Where do you see each of these strings?