# Is there a way to convert "\uxxxx" to text by C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, visual-studio-2019, utf-16

I need to storage some Unicode character using a format like '\uxxxx'.(e.g.\u6D4B). But I can't convert it back to text. I'm using UTF-16, not UTF-8.The way that works on UTF-8 will decode into a wrong character. I tried many ways but they all falied. So I want to know if there a way to do such convertion using C++. No matter using Windows API or boost library or something else.

This is the function I wrote:

```
CString Decode(CString mark)
{
    int chrnum;
    sscanf(CStringA(mark).GetBuffer(), "\u%X", &chrnum);
    mark.Format(L"%X", chrnum);
    unsigned int chr = std::stoul(CStringA(mark).GetBuffer(), nullptr, 16);
    wchar_t wchr[2] = { boost::numeric_cast<wchar_t>(chr) ,L'\000' };
    mark = CString(wchr);
    return mark;
}
```

But it outputs nothing.

My encode function as follows:

```
CString Encode(TCHAR chr)
{
    int recv = static_cast<int>(chr);
    CString ret;
    ret.Format(L"\\u%5X", recv);
    return ret;
}
```

Here is an example:

Input:
`\u6D4B`

Output:
`测`

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28534221/c-convert-asii-escaped-unicode-string-into-utf8-string) answer your question?

Comment: @CoryKramer Isn't using the algorithm in that link a bit risky on Windows where a `wchar_t` is only 16 bits?

Comment: I'll have a try,thank you.

Comment: @Cory Kramer No,it gives me a anther character. My encode is using Unicode but the converter is using utf-8. I have added my encode function to the question.

Comment: `\u...` does not work the way you seem to imagine. Backslash escapes like this are interpreted and evaluated at _compile-time_, not at run-time.

Comment: @CoryKramer great reference. the reference inside the accepted  reply must do the trick.

Comment: @500-internal-server-error  I know. So I'm looking for a run-time way.

Comment: @red-wave This does not output right character.It can't' pass the example test.