# In answer by a POST sent, I get unicode characteres. How to get the ASCII representation?

Tags: c#, unicode, ascii

This is the answer:

> \u003c html\u003e \u003c body\u003e Esta búsqueda ya se ha completado
>   . \u003c / body\u003e \u003c / html\u003e

And it should be:

```
<html><body>Esta búsqueda ya se ha completado.</body></html>
```

The script that I have used:

```
    public String reemplazarCaracteres(String texto)
    {
        UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
        Byte[] encodedBytes = utf8.GetBytes(texto);
        String decodedString = utf8.GetString(encodedBytes);

        return decodedString;

    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at Adam's `DecodeEncodedNonAsciiCharacters()` method here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615559/converting-unicode-strings-to-escaped-ascii-string

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm.

Just I Would like adding that, you need 

using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

in order to use Regex.