# C# convert a string to unicode encoding

Tags: c#, .net

I need to convert a string i.e. "hi" to & #104;& #105; is there a simple way of doing this? Here is a website that does what I need. http://unicode-table.com/en/tools/encoder/

Comment: Do you have some code that you've tried?

Comment: You want the HTML hex values for the string, or do you actually want to switch from one encoding to another?

Comment: this will do the trick in javascript

<!-- 
function display(){if(document.forms[0].ascii.value != ''){var vText = document.forms[0].ascii.value; 
         var vEncoded = display2(vText); document.forms[0].unicode.value = vEncoded;}} 
function display2(source){result = '';for (i=0; i<source.length; i++) result += '&#' + source.charCodeAt(i) + ';'; 
  return result;} 
//-->

Comment: the html hex values for the string.

Comment: @Andy you may want to put your code (even in JS) in the post to show what you've tried. (Also converting the JS you've added in comment to C# should be trivial - you may as well explain what problem you've faced when converting).

Comment: sorry had a hard time explaining this. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var s = "hi";
var ss = String.Join("", s.Select(c => "&#" + (int)c + ";"));
```

Comment: this works very well and the answer below. I appreciate all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string myString = "Hi there!";
string encodedString = myString.Aggregate("", (current, c) => current + string.Format("&#{0};", Convert.ToInt32(c)));
```

Comment: Fancy, but one should not build long string with string concatenation... If rebuilding `String.Join` with `Enumerable.Aggregate` you should still use `StringBuilder`...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615559/converting-unicode-strings-to-escaped-ascii-string):

```
    static string EncodeNonAsciiCharacters(string value)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (char c in value)
        {
            string encodedValue = "&#" + ((int)c).ToString("d4"); // <------- changed
            sb.Append(encodedValue);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```