# can't display Arabic characters in unity using c#

Tags: c#, facebook, unity-game-engine, soomla

Hi I have a game in unity and use c# and I made login with Facebook using Soomla profile package but my problem is when the user logged in if his username in Arabic it display like that

> \u062a\u064a\u0646

**I try to some thing like this**

```
 byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(profile.Username);
 string my = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
username.text = my + " "+Lang.MainScreenWelcome;
```

but nothing work.

Note i know that unity didn't support Arabic but in normal it display like that

> ت ي ي ي ن ش

so I am using plugin for that in normal case but this case with Facebook it didn't work

Comment: Those characters are outside the ASCII range. Try `Encoding.UTF8` instead. Unless you mean that `profile.Username` literally contains `\u062a\u064a...`, in the case of which you might be interested in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1615860/996081).

Comment: thanks a lot  the answer link was exactly what i want and work perfect thanks again you save my time

Comment: @cubrr, you should post that as an answer.