# C# Convert Unicode chars

Tags: c#, json, unicode, encoding, streamreader

is it possible to convert a string like "\u00e8" (Got it by reading a WebRequestResponse with Streamreader) to it's unicode char(è)?
Tried many things with Encoding, but nothing works.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried, so we don't offer solutions that have already not worked for you.

Comment: Can you show how the code, best done in an [mcve], you *tried* to set the encoding?

Comment: Presumably this text is part of something else - is it JSON? If so, just use a JSON parser...

Comment: I've tried using every available Encoding at 'new StreamReader(dataStream, Encoding.<AlreadyTriedEveryoneAvailable>)'
Yes it is JSon, also tried HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Source), but it also doesn't do what i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Regex.Unescape()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape(v=vs.110).aspx), which unescapes any escape sequences that are valid for a Regex (including `\uXXXX`). Note that it also unescapes other sequences like `\t`, `\n`, and `\[`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked!

Comment: Two downvotes and absolutely no explanation. Can someone clue me in here? I also found the following: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31362213/2524589 They suggest using System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(string)