# How to serialize special characters with JsonSerializing

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I have a json data with Serbian Characters! When i want to get this data i need JsonSeriaize and data transform for example `Željko Cvijetić` To `}\u0001eljko Cvijeti\u0007\u0001`

Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Here i have Json Result example

```
"SMSFlowMessages": [
{
  "Display": "Example",
  "MessageId": 104,
  "MessageText": "Dear }\u0001eljko Cvijeti\u0007\u0001, the 22-05-2018 it will be your Birthday!!\nIn this special day you will have double points on all products!\n\nExample Team"
},
{
  "Display": "Example",
  "MessageId": 105,
  "MessageText": "Dear test test, the 22-05-2035 it will be your Birthday!!\nIn this special day you will have double points on all products!\n\nExample Team"
},
```

Here my C# Code

```
  JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { Culture = new CultureInfo("sr-Latn-CS") };
    json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, settings);

     root.SMSFlowMessages.Clear();
     root.ViberFlowMessages.Clear();

      try
      {

      log.append("SMS SEND>>START:" + Environment.NewLine + json + Environment.NewLine + ">>END", logdir);

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiurl);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        var stringContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var getresult = client.PostAsync(apiurl, stringContent).Result;
        string resultContent = getresult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        log.append("SMS RECV<<START:" + Environment.NewLine + resultContent + Environment.NewLine + "<<END", logdir);

         smsflag = "";
         json = "";

         }
```

Comment: You need to convert your text before JSONing it. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615559/convert-a-unicode-string-to-an-escaped-ascii-string

Comment: Why does `Ž` turn into `}\u0001`? What weird encoding scheme is this?

Answer (score 17):

Altough this thread is quite old by now I'll try to help some people that stumble across this thread after me. 
I dont really understand the main problem or intention of this thread but I think saulyasar misformulated his question. I'll interpret his question as: How can I serialize my string "Željko Cvijetić" into JSON without the characters being converted to something like "}\u0001".

The answer to this is quite simple:

```
var output = JsonSerializer.Serialize("Željko Cvijetić", new JsonSerializerOptions
                {
                    WriteIndented = true,
                    Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.Default
                });

-> output: "\"\\u017Deljko Cvijeti\\u0107\""
```

converts the string to JSON but converts the special characters, while

```
var output = JsonSerializer.Serialize("Željko Cvijetić", new JsonSerializerOptions
                {
                    WriteIndented = true,
                    Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping
                });

-> output: "\"Željko Cvijetić\""
```

solves the problem by using the UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping Encoder.

Answer (score 13):

JSON supports Unicode and JSON will normally be encoded as UTF-8 when used in an HTTP API. However, if you need to escape non-ASCII characters when serializing to JSON you can specify that using the `JsonSerializerSettings.StringEscapeHandling` property:

```
var text = "Željko Cvijetić";
var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
    StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeNonAscii
};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(text, jsonSerializerSettings);
```

This results in this  JSON:

```
"\u017deljko Cvijeti\u0107"
```

This is not the same as you show in your question but to be honest I have no idea how Ž maps to `"}\u0001"`. Please see [Unicode escape sequences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Unicode_escape_sequences) for how to escape a character in a JavaScript string literal.

Comment: Old answer here, but is the right way and works with strings serialized on cookies too. Thanks