# How to prevent '&' symbol converted to \u0026ID in C#?

Tags: c#

```
var dynamicEdmIndexObject = new DynamicEdmComplexObject();
dynamicEdmIndexObject.Properties["Provider Name"] = 
providerApiInfo.Properties["ProviderName"].ToString();
```

The actual provider name that I'm storing is `P&ID` but the result is coming as `P\u0026ID`.

How to prevent this?

Comment: its getting encoded. try decoding it

Comment: What is `providerApiInfo`? What is the dynamic type of `providerApiInfo.Properties["ProviderName"]`? Does it have a custom `ToString()` implementation?

Comment: Kindly share complete sample code.

Comment: "&" == "\u0026"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a Unicode string to an escaped ASCII string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615559/convert-a-unicode-string-to-an-escaped-ascii-string)

Comment: @RaymondChen am getting providerApiInfo from MongoDB like below
`var providerApiInfo = (new CrudManager<ProviderApi>(0)).ReadOne(providerId, "_id") as ProviderApi;`

When I checked value for provider name in MongoDB it is "P&ID"  but when I see value after ToString() it is P\u0026ID. it is not having any custom ToString() implementation.