# Writing "latin1" encoded byte array with escape characters

Tags: mysql, vb.net, character-encoding

I'm working on a database import/export process in VB.NET which writes data from a MySQL (5.5) database to a plain text file.  The application reads the data to a `DataTable`, then goes through the rows/columns to actually write the data to the `OutputFile` (`System.IO.StreamWriter` object).  The encoding on the tables in this database is `Latin1`.  There is a `MediumBlob` field in one of the tables I've been using for testing which contains image files stored as a byte array.

In my attempts to validate the output from my application, I've exported the data directly from the database using the MySQL Workbench, then compared that with the results I get when I write the same data from my application.  In the direct export from MySQL Workbench, I see some of these bytes are exported with the backslash.  When I read the data through my application, however, this escape character does not appear.  Viewed through Notepad++, it clearly shows some distinct differences between the two output results (see screenshot).

[image: Notepad++ comparison of output results]

Obviously, while apparently very similar, the two are not completely identical.  My application is not including the backslashes for escaped characters, and some characters such as `NULL` are coming out differently altogether.  My code for writing this field to the file is:

```
OutputFile.Write("'" & System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(28591).GetString(CType(COPYRow(ColumnIndex), Byte())) & "'")
```

There doesn't appear to be an overload for the `GetString` method that allows me to specify an escape character, so I'm wondering if there's another way that, using this method, I can ensure the characters are correctly encoded, including escape characters.

I'm "assuming" that this method should also work in general when I start working with my PostgreSQL database, but with possibly a different encoding.  I'm trying to build things as "generic" as possible, but I'll have to worry about specifying encodings at run-time instead of hard-coding them later.

---

#### EDIT

I just ran across another SO question, which might point me in the right direction: [Convert a Unicode string to an escaped ASCII string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615559/convert-a-unicode-string-to-an-escaped-ascii-string).  Obviously, it might take a bit more work to get it right, but this looks like the closest thing to what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: It's not clear, to me, what you're trying to do. Are you trying to conver an Image bytes to a US-ASCII representation? Or `iso-8859-1` encoded strings to US-ASCII, preserving the non-convertible CodePoints to the escaped Unicode representation as ASCII text? What's the use of these?

Comment: MySQL Workbench is showing you a "debugging" output (probably of its own invention). Why do you want your text file to be anything but a straightforward text file with a specific character encoding? (Or, why not a clean JSON file [which would use UTF-8]?).

Comment: For binary data, ideally, it wouldn't come out of your data access layer as a .NET String. A String is a text data type. If it must be a String can you convert the data on the server side to a Base64 string?

Comment: Perhaps I'm over-thinking things (or thinking about it incorrectly), but the intent is to be able to export the data in a format that is usable for importing back into the database at potentially some point in the future. To that end, I am comparing the output produced by my application to the output produced by MySQL Workbench and trying to reproduce the latter as closely as possible.  Additionally, I ***may*** need to be able to transfer this data from one RDBMS to another (MySQL -> PostgreSQL or vice-versa), so I want to ensure the data is as "clean" as possible.

Comment: You are over-thinking it. For Text fields, [read the Collation value](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-mysql.html) and reproduce the Encoding when saving the Text to a file. Or, convert everything to UTF-8, if possible. Byte Arrays  representing Bitmaps must remain as they are. You might, if really required, [convert the array to a Base64 representation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string).

Comment: Might that be Arabic (`د؈`)?  And your charset is `macroman`?