# C# How to convert \uxxxx to plaintext (hex escape sequence)

Tags: c#, hex

I wanna know how I could convert an appearance of the hex escape sequence "\uxxxx" (where x is a hex digit) to plaintext, i.e. "\\uxxxx" so I can print it somewhere.
I tried

```
string convertedString = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape("\u1234");
```

but the string gets some strange value. Same with Escape. [image: Regex.Unescape does not "convert any escaped characters in the input string"]
[image]
I tried something like

```
convertedString = ("\u1234").Replace("\u", "\\u");
```

but compiler tells me "Unrecognized escape sequence" because he expects 4 more digits.

[image: "Unrecognized escape sequence"]

Also not working:

```
string convertedString = ("\u1234").Replace(@"\u", @"\\u");
```

[image]

Hope somebody can help me. :)

Comment: `Replace("\\u", "\\\\u")`, or `Replace(@"\u", @"\\u")`. You were also looking for `Regex.Escape`, not `Regex.Unescape`

Comment: Tried it but nothing works.

Comment: Ah I see what you're doing. When you write `"\u1234"`, the compiler turns that into the `ሴ` character. When your code runs, it's looking at the string `"ሴ"`, and not the string `"\1234"`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615559/convert-a-unicode-string-to-an-escaped-ascii-string