# what is the difference between a literal string and a variable string writing in unicode

Tags: c#

if I run this code in a wpf app

```
TextBox1.Text = trueContent;  //trueContent = "\u5929\u554a"
```

the testbox will only show the "\u5929\u554a"
but if i run the below code

```
TextBox1.Text = "\u5929\u554a";
```

I will get the right result
so what is the difference between a literal string and a variable string writing in unicode

Comment: My bet is that `trueContent = "\\u5929\\u554a"`

Comment: Or `@"\u5929\u554a"`

Comment: Where did the value of `trueContent` come from? How are you seeing its value?

Comment: Even in the IL the Unicode char will be interpreted. The only way to preserve the unicode as typed is to either escape or use the literal @ equivalent https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQyDMABGgQMIEDeOB1RhyALAQLIAUAlBTVwTgJC8A3AIYAnAgBkwwAKYihEAgF4iyAEQAdAK4BWAJypdW7dvpDVAbj6DRBAKIBnAMZCADtJhKCGo/sNGTZpbY/MJiAHIA9iIAtvKeGjq+/qYWVDQAvjjpQA

Comment: It's the compiler who processes escape sequences. It sees "\u..." sequence in your string literal - it replaces it with unicode character. If string came from some external source (file etc) - then compiler have nothing to do with it and it stays as is

Comment: If you need to convert char to it's `\u` unicode equivalent you can use something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615559/convert-a-unicode-string-to-an-escaped-ascii-string

Comment: Hey guys， after reading the comment, I debugged the program using visualstudio (the program is debugged using Rider when asking this question) and in visualstudio the content of trueContent is "\\u5929\\u554a" but in Rider is "\u5929\u554a", so as one of the comment says , the trueContent is "\\u5929\\u554a", thank you. That helps me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys， after reading the comment, I debugged the program using visualstudio (the program is debugged using Rider when asking this question) and in visualstudio the content of trueContent is "\u5929\u554a" but in Rider is "\u5929\u554a", so as one of the comment says , the trueContent is "\u5929\u554a", thank you. That helps me a lot