# Where can I find System.Web.Helpers, System.Web.WebPages, and System.Web.Razor?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, razor, razorgenerator

I am following this [article](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/08/01/text-templating-using-razor-the-easy-way.aspx) on RazorGenerator and it say's that I must add references to:

- `System.Web.Helpers.dll`
- `System.Web.WebPages.dll`
- `System.Web.Razor.dll`

The only one I can see when I do `Add Reference` is `System.Web.Razor`, but I don't know where the other ones are.

Comment: Possible duplicate question: [System.Web.Helpers not found in VS2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34402956/system-web-helpers-not-found-in-vs2015/34403205)

Answer (score 33):

You will find these assemblies in the Extensions group under Assemblies in Visual Studio 2010, 2012 & 2013 (Reference Manager)

Comment: I believe question says in Visual Studio 2010 (look at the tags)

Comment: Nope, I didn't find these assemblies in the Extensions (VS 2015, MVC 4, .NET 4.5.2)

Comment: I think they are part of `Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages` (which is dependent on `Microsoft.AspNet.Razor` which is also needed for some of these namespaces) today.

Answer (score 23):

To sum up all of the options for VS 2017, WebHelpers was installed by installing MVC in previous versions of Visual Studio. If you're getting this error, you probably don't have the older versions of VS installed anymore.

So, installing the `Microsoft.AspNet.MVC` NuGet package will require `Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages` and `Microsoft.AspNet.Razor`, and the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages` includes `System.Web.Helpers.dll`.

If you've got direct references to System.Web.Mvc.dll and you don't want to use NuGet for MVC, you can get the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages` NuGet, or there are some other NuGet packages that only contain `System.Web.Helpers.dll`, like the `microsoft-web-helpers` or `System-Web-Helpers.dll`packages.

There appear to be 2 versions of `System.Web.Helpers.dll`, one for .Net 4.0 and one for 4.5. Choosing the correct version of MVC or AspNet.WebPages will ensure you get the right one.

Comment: System.Web.Helpers.dll in the System-Web-Helpers.dll nuget package is the latest and works with VS 2017.  Contains just the System.Web.Helpers.dll.  That's all.

Answer (score 17):

As for VS2017 I didn't find it in "extensions", there's a Nuget package called "[microsoft-web-helpers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft-web-helpers)" that seems to be equivalent to System.Web.Helpers.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem , first I couldn't find those `dlls` in the list of `.NET components` . but later I figured it out that the solution is :

1- first I changed `target framework` from `.NET framework 4 client profile` to `.NET framework 4`.

2- then **scroll down** the list of `.NET components` , **pass first list** of `system.web.`.. , **scroll down** , and find the **second list** of `system.web.`.. at the bottom , they're there .

I hope this could help others

Comment: In Visual Studio 2012, look in the Extensions filter on the left hand-side, as per comment below - in case you don't read that far (as I did not).

Comment: What do you mean by pass the firs list? there is only one list and can be sorted with component name! what is the name you are referring to? to see those DLL's MVC3 should be installed and it won't install if you don't have IIS in your computer

Answer (score 13):

In VS 2010 just right click on project or on reference and click add reference.
On the popup window Select Assemblies - > Extensions  ->  System.Web.Helpers

Comment: Visual studio 2010 does not have Select Assemblies or Extensions or ... You are referring to Visual Studio 2012 and above

Comment: For VS 2010      select project References->add Reference->.NET tab-> click Component Name to organize list->should see system.web.helpers..

Comment: System.Web.Helpers does not exist under Select Assemblies - > Extensions

Answer (score 12):

Installing ASP.NET MVC3 from [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3) should help.

Comment: I don't think MVC3 will help. Here are my references of a MVC3 project: http://i.imgur.com/414j8.png. I don't have them either.

Comment: Thanks, this was the root cause of the issue for me.

Answer (score 8):

This particular NuGet package has a habit of losing its references in one of our projects. From time to time I will need to run the following command in the Package Manager Console to restore the references and everything is OK again

```
Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Webpages -reinstall
```

Answer (score 6):

On VS2017 I installed the NuGet package: Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages

That did the trick.

Answer (score 5):

I had to install `RazorGenerator.Templating` to get it all to work. From the NuGet console, type:

`Install-Package RazorGenerator.Templating`

Answer (score 4):

They should be under `C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.Net` (or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.Net` if you're on a 64-bit OS) in a subfolder for MVC3 or WebPages.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is a missing or outdated version of MVC. I was running VS 2015Preview and could resolve the issue by installing the latest version of MVC via NuGet.

Just in case anyone is still coming across this one.

Answer (score 1):

When you install this nuget package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages they can be find in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.x.x.x\lib\net45