# why can't reference System.Web.WebPages and System.Web.Razor in a WPF project?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, razor, razorgenerator

I need to use `Razor Generator` as described [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/08/01/text-templating-using-razor-the-easy-way.aspx) in a `WPF` project but I can't add **references** to `System.Web.WebPages` and `System.Web.Razor` required by `RAZOR Generator`. are these dlls unavailable in `WPF` in general ? or I should change some **configurations** ?

Comment: why do you want to reference this assemblies in wpf project?

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov : these are required by RAZOR Generator

Comment: Razor generator is for generating classes from cshtml files as far as i know. But in wpf application there is no such files. So i ask again why do you want to use it in your wpf application?

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov : I want to create and save static html files using templates and user contents

Comment: What is the target type of your WPF project? If .net 4.0 client profile change it to .net 4.0 and you should able to add the references.

Comment: How it is seen "can't add references to System.Web.WebPages and System.Web.Razor". Is there any error? I try it in my VS (2012) and it become referenced without problems.

Comment: @nemesv : it was .net 4.0 client profile and I changed it to .net 4.0 but no difference .

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov :  I can't find them in the list of .NET dlls

Comment: They are in Extensions, not in Framework

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov : sorry , but I didn't get the point ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why , but by installing [RazorGenerator.Templating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037895/where-can-i-find-system-web-helpers-system-web-webpages-and-system-web-razor) through NuGet ,all errors disappear , and it's working now .

**update :**

I finally could find those `dll`s . the solution is :

1- first I changed `target framework` from `.NET framework 4 client profile` to `.NET framework 4`.

2- then **scrolled down** the list of `.NET components` , **passed first list** of `system.web.`.. , **scrolled down** , and I **found a second list** of `system.web.`.. at the bottom , they were there .

I hope this could help others

Answer (score 3):

Did you search in Extensions (see screen shot)?
[image]

Comment: no , I have vs 2010 .I don't know how but it is solved by adding RazorGenerator.Templating through NuGet ! thank you anyway