# Getting JSON data from a response stream and reading it as a string?

Tags: c#, json, winforms, httpwebresponse

I am trying to read a response from a server that I receive when I send a POST request. Viewing fiddler, it says it is a JSON response. How do I decode it to a normal string using C# Winforms with preferably no outside APIs. I can provide additional code/fiddler results if you need them.

The fiddler and gibberish images:

[image: Gibberish][image: JSON]

The gibberish came from my attempts to read the stream in the code below:

```
Stream sw = requirejs.GetRequestStream(); 
sw.Write(logBytes, 0, logBytes.Length); 
sw.Close(); 
response = (HttpWebResponse)requirejs.GetResponse();
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream(); 
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream); 
MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadToEnd());
```

Comment: "preferably no outside APIs."   Use an outside API, like Newtonsoft.Json (also called JSON.NET).

Comment: Do you need it as a string for display, or do you need to utilize the data contained within (meaning you need it available as an array/list)?

Comment: @SteveWellens - OP wants to read response as string which indeed requires no external APIs. Parsing may need JSON.Net... Code looks reasonable. Obviously creation is missing and OP may need to read about [encodings](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) which is likley the reason of the output.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - Thank you for reiterating the OP's desires.  I think he will find that trying to create an object from a JSON string is a lot of work and using a 3rd party library is an acceptable way to go.  I was nudging him in the direction he will likely go.

Comment: @r3mus I need it as a string so I can then send it as a header

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, Newtonsoft.Json is really a good library and worth using -- very lightweight.

If you really want to only use Microsoft's .NET libraries, also consider System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.

```
var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
var jsonObject = serializer.DeserializeObject(sr.ReadToEnd());
```

Comment: Thanks! Does HTTPWebRequest in an HTTPS connection prevent it from being deserialized? Because the login is an HTTPS connection, and I know the JSON is valid, but when I attempt to deserialize it, it doesn't succeed, saying "Invalid JSON Primitive". Am I missing something here?

Comment: I've never had an issue decoding responses from an HTTPS connection.  What's the raw text you get back that the decode fails on?

Answer (score 3):

Going to assume (you haven't clarified yet) that you need to actually *decode* the stream, since A) retrieving a remote stream of text is well documented, and B) you can't do anything much with a non-decoded JSON stream.

Your best course of action is to implement [`System.Web.Helpers.Json`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json%28v=vs.111%29.aspx):

```
using System.Web.Helpers.Json
...
var jsonObj = Json.Decode(jsonStream);
```

Comment: How to find System.Web.Helpers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037895/where-can-i-find-system-web-helpers-system-web-webpages-and-system-web-razor