# System.Web.Helpers not found in VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, helper

I'm trying to add some JSON parsing to the C# code in VS2015 but I can't find:

System.Web.Helpers

as the MS documentation suggests.  I've looked at other people's questions of a similar nature (almost all on earlier versions) and the answers all say to add it in the Assemblies / Framework dialog.

The problem is it doesn't appear in that dialog, nor do many of the other things I see people talking about.

I would really appreciate any help on fixing this.

Here is the list I have access to:

[image: Assemblies - Framework List for VS2015 - C#]

**Edit:** Added the Extensions window as well

[image: VS2015 Assemblies - Extensions window]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find System.Web.Helpers, System.Web.WebPages, and System.Web.Razor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037895/where-can-i-find-system-web-helpers-system-web-webpages-and-system-web-razor)

Comment: Thanks - but I've worked through all that already.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This question is a bit old but here's a simple solution - Microsoft seemed to just move this library to a Nuget package called "[microsoft-web-helpers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft-web-helpers)". Installing that package seems to be equivalent to having the assembly.

Comment: Thank you! You saved my day

Comment: This package is not compatible with ASP.NET MVC

Comment: I also have problems using it with ASP.NET Web Forms. But when I uninstall the package again, the reference to System.Web.Helpers still keeps working. So, that's my workaround currently...

Answer (score 6):

Old question but might still help someone.

You must install MVC 3 in order to have the System.Web.Helpers Extension on VS2015.

link to download: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1491

Comment: Link is dead now

Comment: In my case, MVC 4 was required: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30683

Answer (score 5):

You cannot find it because of the simple fact that's not part of the Framework assemblies (what you are looking at).

It's part of the Extensions assemblies, and, as posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13217762/3932049), you will find it under "Extensions" in the left-hand side of the dialog.

[image: Look at this]

Comment: Again, thanks for the reply - but I've been there too!  Mine goes from System.spacial to System.Windows.Interactivity.

Comment: @DaveEP make sure you update everything in VisualStudio in case a pending ASP.NET has fu**ed something up

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon the same issue and fixed it by adding NuGet Package ->
Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages

Answer (score 1):

I was wanting to work with JSON as well in an ASP.Net project using VS2015.
I ended up here trying to find answers. Right about the time I finished reading the other answers on this post I noticed my project already had a reference to `Newtonsoft.Json`. Never heard of it before so I looked it up; I'm glad I did.

It was literally a one liner to Serialize a `List<String>` to `JSON`.
You can pass in an `Object` so you should be able to serialize most any Object within reason.

**Ultimately I didn't need to install MVC3 or reference System.Web.Helpers**

Hope this helps!

[image][NewtonSoft Serializing and Deserializing JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm)