# VisualStudio ASP.net MVC - CS0103: The name 'model' does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm simply trying to add a project to an existing solution, but I keep getting the following:
[image]

**So I have also tried to create a standalone project, which works and builds**.
However when I add it as an existing project into the solution I get the same error again when viewing.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: That error is often the result of an incorrect `web.config` file in the `Views` folder

Comment: I don't know if this will solve your problem, but hopefully, it will help you find the missing namespaces. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037895/where-can-i-find-system-web-helpers-system-web-webpages-and-system-web-razor

Comment: But it builds ok when its standalone?

Answer (score 0):

Check Your namespace is correctly defined or not