# How to deal with escapable values in Azure Table Storage REST API

Tags: azure, escaping, code-injection

If I run an "insert entity" request with a body like:

```
{
   "PartitionKey":[PartitionKey]",
   "RowKey":"[RowKey]",
   "Message":"[Message]"
}
```

What do I do if `[Message]` contains "strange" characters, e.g.

```
",\n   invalidinvalidinvalid
```

Is there a way to escape the values so that they are still parsed correctly by Azure? Will typical HTML escaping accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data being posted must be a valid JSON document, so you need to escape special characters like backslashes `\\` and double-quotes `\"`. How you do this will depend on which language, most have a JSON  library to handle this sort of thing.

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18104891/417803) gave me the rest of the details needed. C# doesn't have a good library for constructing JSON messages without creating a 1:1 correspondence with a data structure.

Comment: Maybe JSON.NET with an anonymous or dynamic object?

Comment: oops sorry I meant "core C#". External libraries are a no-go for binary size reasons.

Comment: although actually JSON.NET is pretty tiny. I'll look into it, thanks!