# Write JSON messages in C# using core .NET?

Tags: c#, json

Is there built-in .NET support for building JSON messages (with escaping)? I can't use external libraries like JSON.NET because of binary size.

Thanks!

Edit: I was hoping to just have a message constructor without the constraint of creating a strict datatype, but I guess it's good enough.

Edit2: Actually it's not good enough. I'm looking to write JSON messages that don't correspond in a naive 1:1 way to a data structure, but it looks like I just have to write my own escaping, a la [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18104891/417803)

Comment: `JavaScriptSerializer` `DataContractJsonSerializer`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score -1):

Check [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) Class

Comment: Why downvote ? Please add comment atleast